# Is there an equivalent of the markdown_in_html_blocks extension for latex environments?

Tags: pandoc

I like being able to write markdown within html (e.g. div tags).

I'd also like to do the same in latex environments. For example, in a beamer presentation:

```
\note{ This _could_ **be** *formatted* }
```

or

```
\begin{blockquote}

This _could_ **be** *formatted*

\end{blockquote}
```

Is there currently any simple way of doing this with pandoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the right way to do this now is to use filters http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html. This is a new feature which has enabled some custom extensions to pandoc markdown in packages like pandoc-gpp  http://testdriventrekkie.com/pandoc-gpp/

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, [Markdown is not parsed in LaTeX environments](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pandoc-discuss/oZETB5Ii1Cw/Xa2i0ii2ZhMJ). You'll need to use LaTeX or create a work-around.