# Pandoc Markdown: ignore text in PDF (but include in HTML)

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I am writing a Markdown report with both PDF and HTML output using Pandoc. I'd like some text will appear in HTML but not in PDF. The solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812365/pandoc-markdown-omit-text-in-pdf-version-but-include-in-html-version) isn't working for me.

What I tried so far:

```
My text for both HTML and PDF <div>My HTML code for HTML only</div>
```

and I make PDF with

```
~/.cabal/bin/pandoc -s -N --toc --template=default.latex -f markdown-markdown_in_html_blocks -o reproducibleResearch.pdf reproducibleResearch.md
```

`~/.cabal/bin/pandoc` contains the last version of Pandoc (`~/.cabal/bin/pandoc`) while Ubuntu still has 1.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original markdown HTML blocks (the kind pandoc parses when you turn of the `markdown_in_html_blocks` extension, as you are doing) must start at the beginning of the line.  From the [markdown syntax description](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> The only restrictions are that block-level HTML elements — e.g. `<div>`, `<table>`, `<pre>`, `<p>`, etc. — must be separated from surrounding content by blank lines, and the start and end tags of the block should not be indented with tabs or spaces. Markdown is smart enough not to add extra (unwanted) `<p>` tags around HTML block-level tags.

So this is what you need:

```
My text.

<div>
This will be ignored in non-HTML output
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works.

I already tried to add a blank line before the HTML block but it didn't work because it requires also a newline after <div> and before </div>.

Comment: This doesn't work in recent versions of pandoc.  This does however: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48083891/1175053

Answer (score 0):

There was another question on stackoverflow that was asking about [markdown_in_html_blocks extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835611/is-there-an-equivalent-of-the-markdown-in-html-blocks-extension-for-latex-enviro).  According to that thread markdown isn't parsed in latex.

However, there is a link to [pandoc's google groups page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pandoc-discuss/oZETB5Ii1Cw/Xa2i0ii2ZhMJ) that recommend using something like the following '\begin{landscape}' and another for '\end{landscape}'.

Comment: Thank you Ryan.I think these are two different questions. If Markdown is not parsed, then the text is printed out without to be formatted. By the way, I am looking how print a text only in HTML output and not in TEX/PDF output. Hope someone can help me.